# how to format string to date in shell correctly

Tags: bash, shell

I am generating string using `date +"%Y%m%d%H"` and reading the same string to convert back as date. somehow  reverse is not working. and %Y is treated as first six characters

```
# date +"%Y%m%d%H"
2017030216

# date -d 2017030215 +%Y
201703

# date -d 2017030215 +%m
02
```

Why doesn't this return 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing invalid strings to `-d`, i.e. strings which are not in accordance with its expected format.  The documentation of that format is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html

"2017030215" is not a valid date/time string in most systems, and `date -d` is no exception.  If you want to see how `date -d` is interpreting your string, just run it without the `+` option to see the full output.  You'll probably be surprised.